# Why are the stars not visible in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, ratings

I want to rate a Podcast and had a hard time finding the stars which are not displayed in my macOS iTunes. Using Windows I managed to find out where they are. Is this disabled in macOS iTunes or is it just a bug? I already checked the checkbox in the preferences. No change.

[image: Missing stars]
[image: In Windows I can see them]

Comment: I just cross checked with the same podcast, and I am able to see the fine. Care to share the version of iTunes running on macOS? I have iTunes Version 12.9.4.94 running on macOS Mojave 10.14.4

Comment: @NimeshNeema Strange, It tells me there hasn't been enough reviews to display an average rating for me. iTunes 12.9.4.94, macOS 10.14.4, same as you. Perhaps it's because we might be in different countries' iTunes stores?

Comment: @user3052786 I get that too. But I still get the option to rate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsaWB.jpg

Comment: @NimeshNeema Oh yeah, I misunderstood, I see the exact same thing. So the OP is asking about the clickable stars to rate, not the average rating stars. Maybe it's a localization issue?

Comment: @user3052786 Apparently OP is not able to see the rating starts. As I understand (with a little help from Google Translate), OP has already rated the Podcast. But why the stars aren't displayed is beyond me.

Comment: @NimeshNeema: I rated it using my Windows machine as I was not able to rate it on my Mac. I have 12.9.4.94 running on macOS Mojave 10.14.4.